# The node express's bodyParser can't get the parameter in the GET request

Tags: node.js, parameters, get, express

I ajax an GET request in client side:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/update',             
        type: 'get',    
        data: {
            "key": key,
            "value": value
        },
        success: function (data, err) {

        }
    })
```

then at the node side, I want get the parameter

```
var showParam = function (req, res) {
    if (req.body) {
        for (var key in req.body) {
            console.log(key + ": " + req.body[key]);
        }       
        res.send({status:'ok',message:'data received'});
    } else {
        console.log("nothing received");
        res.send({status:'nok',message:'no Tweet received'});
    }   
}
app.get('/update', function(req, res){
    showParam(req, res);
})
```

The shell show the body is empty and undefined.

But when I change the `get` to `post` (both at the client side and server side), everything is ok, I can get the parameter correctly.

What's problem with my code? Do I miss something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are issuing a GET request, the URL parameters are not part of the body, and thus will not be parsed by the bodyParser middleware.

To access the query parameters, just reference [`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query)

Answer (score 2):

You can access your data for get request in server-side by using `req.query.key` and `req.query.value`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get params from `bodyParser` you must use `POST` not `GET`. Your ajax request and server calls must both use `POST`.

http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body

```
app.post('/update', function(req, res){
    showParam(req, res);
});

$.ajax({
        url: '/update',             
        type: 'POST',    
        data: {
            "key": key,
            "value": value
        },
        success: function (data, err) {

        }
    });
```

To get the `GET` params, use the `url` module and use `query = url.parse(req.url, true).query`. `query` will contain an object with the values accessible via `query.foo`

Comment: So, if I want get parameter from get request on the server side, what should I do?

Comment: Thank you very much, but I wonder why the `bodyParser` could not just parse the get parameter too?I think if it could do this job, it could be better

Comment: Not really on topic, but how would you defer parameter `foo` from `POST` and parameter `foo` from `GET`? Please upvote/checkmark this as the answer. :)